Cannot accept agreement during SAP Install in Terminal
I am trying to install SAP Server on Ubuntu but during install, i cannot accept agreement. Tab is not working. Could you please help me?



Hit the "space" bar until  you get to the end and then see if it gives you an offer to accept.  If not, hit "Q" and see if it prompts.  (If this works I'll make it an answer)

@ThomasWard space just keep writing space, i hold for long time but nothing changed. Also pressing Q is just typing q to screen.

I edited the license agreement file and shorten it to visible area on screenshot. After that, i started install again and it asked me to write yes. so worked for now.

That is a useful workaround. Consider posting that as an answer.

Sorry, my bad. I am just newbie

I edited the license agreement file and shorten it to visible area on screenshot. After that, i started install again and it asked me to write yes. so worked for now.
